# Mocking many modules using a function

Tags: jestjs

I have made mocks for frequently-called endpoints, but do not want to call `jest.mock` many times for each test. For this reason I created the following function:

```js
// src/endpoints/__utils__/mockEndpoints.ts
export function mockEndpoints(): void {
  jest.mock('../do-log-in');
  jest.mock('../get-api-key');
  jest.mock('../get-rsa-key');
  // etc
}
```

Unfortunately calling this function inside my test is not working.
The paths inside `jest.mock` are paths relative to the file.
I checked them with `require.resolve` and they do resolve to the correct location.
Using `jest.mock(require.resolve(path))` also did not work.
I have also tried giving `mockEndpoints` jest as an argument to make sure it is using the right instance. But that also did not work

I found the following note on the docs:

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to be in the same scope as the require/import statement.

Reading this, I have tried importing all the modules I want to mock in the file containing `mockEndpoints()`, and then making sure that this file was the first import of my test file. Unfortunately this also did not work.

My test file looks somewhat like this:

```js
import { mockEndpoints } from '../endpoints/__utils__/mockEndpoints';

mockEndpoint(); // does not do anything

// the following *does* work:
// jest.mock('../endpoints/do-log-in');
// jest.mock('../endpoints/get-api-key');
// jest.mock('../endpoints/get-rsa-key');
// etc

describe('test cases', () => {
  /* test cases that indirectly use the mocked endpoints */
})
```

At this point I am unsure how to continue my quest of achieving this. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was not calling `jest.mock` before the imports. When using `jest.mock` in your test file, jest will automatically hoist it to the top (i.e., before the imports that are being mocked). Jest is unable to automagically do this when when jest.mock is contained in a function as I was doing.

Simply importing this function, calling it, and only then importing other things made it work.

---

An alternative solution uses `setupFiles`:

I was able to achieve the same effect by putting the code inside my `mockEndpoints` function in a file, and putting the path to that file inside the `setupFiles` option inside my jest config. E.g.:

```js
// src/endpoints/__utils__/mockEndpoints.ts
jest.mock('../endpoints/do-log-in');
jest.mock('../endpoints/get-api-key');
jest.mock('../endpoints/get-rsa-key');
```

```js
// jest.config.ts
export default {
  setupFiles: ['./src/endpoints/__utils__/mockEndpoints.ts'],
};
```